# Read a excel file in c++ using visual studio

Tags: c++, excel, structure

I have a project where I must read from an excel file into a c++ program. I must then be able to use this data to carry out calculations, sorting, searching, etc. In the excel file, there are about 20 lines of information that is necessary not necessary for the calculations. after, there are are about 100 lines of raw data to spanning several columns. My question is how to read the first 20 lines and store them, but not use them, and how to read the other 100 lines and columns into a structure, so that I can access their data.

Comment: Why are people voting the question down? If there is a problem with what I asked, let me know.

Comment: Its just that it is kinda nooby which is frowned upon. Don't worry about it. Also I always see questions being down voted :(

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the Excel file to a csv format file which makes it easier. Use `std::ifstream` to open the file, getline to read each comma separated line, and strtok to tokenize the values.

Or, if you have a small and/or fixed number of columns, you can use `fscanf(file,"%g,%g...",...)`

Answer (score 0):

Building upon Auriga's suggestion to convert your file to a `.csv` format,
you can handle the problem in following steps:

1. If the number of lines in the Excel Sheet is uncertain (can be more than or less that `120`), simply read the file until `EOF` is encountered.
2. Store the first `20` lines in a simple String array, since you do not intend to do any calculations with this data.
3. As very well suggested by Auriga, tokenize and save the rest of the data in a 2D-array (or a `vector< vector< datatype > >` for more dynamics, where datatype is the suitable datatype for the data).

Now you can access the data and use it directly from the 2D data structure (Array or Vector).

Cheers!